# Way to break only current test case in case of error in one of tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I use mocha to test website using puppeteer. I have testcases with multiple tests in each of them.

The problem here is if any of tests fails there is no sense to run further tests.

```
describe('testset 1', function() {
  let browser
  let page

  before(async () => {
    browser = new Browser() //
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('/testset1')
  })

  it('test first step', () => {
    // this action opens modal required for step 2
    await page.click('.first-step-button')
    // for some reason modal is not opened and test is failed
    expect(true).to.equal(false)
  })

  it('test second step', () => {
    // No sense to do this because this selector is inside modal
    page.click('.first-step-button')
  })
})


describe('testset 2', function() {
  let browser
  let page

  before(async () => {
    browser = new Browser() //
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('/testset2')
  })

  it('test first step', () => {
    // this action opens modal required for step 2
    await page.click('.first-step-button')
    // for some reason modal is not opened and test is failed
    expect(true).to.equal(false)
  })

  it('test second step', () => {
    // No sense to do this because this selector is inside modal
    page.click('.first-step-button')
  })
})
```

I want to stop running tests from `testset 1` after error on first test and switch to `testset 2`

Is there any way to break only the current test set in case of error during the test inside?

I've tried --bail mocha option but it stops testing right after first error which is not desired. The same behavior even if I do it inside describe section

```
describe('testset 1', function() {
  this.bail(true)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for this purpose

```
afterEach(function() {
  // this is pointed to current Mocha Context
  const {currentTest} = this
  if (currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    // parent is pointed to test set which contains current test
    currentTest.parent.pending = true
  }
})
```

Now all works as expected

```
afterEach(function() {
  const {currentTest} = this
  if (currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    currentTest.parent.pending = true
  }
})

describe('testset 1', function() {
  it('test first step', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(false)
  })

  it('test second step', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })
})

// this will be run after error in `testset 1`
describe('testset 2', function() {
  it('test first step', () => {
    // ...
  })

  // ...
})
```